# Delaying Jquery .live mouseover function

Tags: jquery

I am currently using this code:

```
    $('#startLabel').live('mouseover',function(){
$('.startTooltip').fadeIn();
     });

    $('#startLabel').live('mouseout',function(){
$('.startTooltip').fadeOut();
     });
```

to display a tooltip div when the user hovers over the #startLabel div and hide the tooltip when the user moves the cursor away.

I want to change this so that the tooltip will not appear until the #startLabel div has been hovered over for 3 seconds, could someone tell me how I can do this?

I've tried this:

```
    $('#startLabel').live('mouseover',function(){
    setTimeout( function() {
$('.startTooltip').fadeIn();
}, 3000 );
     });
```

but the tooltip still appears if you hover over it quickly and then hover away.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you want is the [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) function.

You'd use it something like this:

```
var timer;
$('#startLabel').live('mouseover',function(){
    timer = setTimeout( function() {
    $('.startTooltip').fadeIn();
    }, 3000 );
});

$('#startLabel').live('mouseout',function(){
    $('.startTooltip').fadeOut();
    cancelTimeout(timer);
});
```

Essentially setTimeout returns a value that can be used to cancel that timeout so you just cancel it if you move out of the area in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#startLabel').live('mouseout',function(){
    $('.startTooltip').delay(4000).fadeIn();
 });
```

and clear the queue on mouseout by using .stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] ); [(true, false) should do it.]

Comment: delay just delays things being shown. It won't stop the item being shown if you mouse over and out again quickly...

Comment: That is because the animation queue remains even on mouseout. Use .stop() to clear the queue for the selected object

Comment: You should be able to edit your answer to put that in. As it stands your answer is not correct since it suffers from exactly the same problem as the OPs original code.